# create space between bootstrap navbar and jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If i look at the following bootstrap example:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

then there is some space between the jumbotron and the navbar.

I digged into the css of the example and if i disable this (2 times):

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Then the space in between disappears.
When i try to do this myself the `margin-bottom` has no effect.
Why is that? And how do i fix it?
(I did a search but I only find people wanting to remove the gap that I don't have...).

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FOOBAR</a>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Qp9v/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add your desired margin to the top of the .jumbotron because the .navbar is fixed position to the top of the page - so it has no relation in the flow to the .jumbotron.

Comment: If you position: relative the .navbar you can see what's happening http://jsfiddle.net/6Qp9v/1/

Comment: what would be a better fix, adding a margin to the top of .jumbotron or using the relative fix? (I know it would be quite personal I guess)

Comment: hmm for some reason my navbar goes down as well when I use position relative. But in the jsfiddle it doesn't. strange.

Comment: it might be inheriting some styles or being moved by styles that aren't in the fiddle - like, padding from a containing div or margin from another div in the flow before it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some padding top for the body.

```
body{
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
```

Hope this answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

This should work! (To get your desired 20px gap, you need to put 70px here as the navbar takes almost 50px from the top. As the navbar is fixed, margin-top will not work with reference to navbar, rather it will work with respect to the top of the page).

You can also try the following code:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

It will also work!